# Spring: reference all beans of type Foo

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I know that in Spring you can load all beans of a certain type with:

```
ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("spring_foo.xml");
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
Map<String, Foo> beans = factory.getBeansOfType(Foo.class);
```

How can I do this in XML?
E.g. something like:

```
<bean id="fooHandler" class="com.mycompany.FooHandler">
    <property name="foos">
    <map beanType="com.mycompany.Foo" / >
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or better with a list rather than a map?

Comment: Here are links to two questions/answers that should cover the functionality for which you are looking. The first question's answer illustrates how to execute the desired result using @Autowired inside of your class. The second question's answer shows how it can be done using Spring's XML configuration file. - [List Beans By Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450145/spring-list-beans-by-type) - [Inject all beans of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799316/how-to-collect-and-inject-all-beans-of-a-given-type-in-spring-xml-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Java Config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java), which lets you use Java to generate your beans. You can mix it in with existing XML configuration files. See my answer to [Spring 3.0.x - context:component-scan result into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592783/spring-3-0-x-contextcomponent-scan-result-into-list/5592894#5592894)